# Adding new user to groups based on another user with Powershell?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have written a script that creates a new user, and bases some of the user's settings on those of the user's manager.

Now, we have two 'types' of groups where a new user is added to the same one as their new manager.

They are: `GALDN*` and `GRP*MIG`. We have well over 100 of each.

In order to get this script ready for myself, I did this:

```
($Boss.memberof -eq "CN=GALDNOffice,OU=Legal,OU=Team,DC=uk,DC=com" )
{ Add-ADGroupMember GALDNOffice $SamID } 
else {  }
```

Now, this is obviously great if I'm just doing it for a couple of groups or add groups when they come along. But now I have been asked to write this up for our Service Desk, and I don't really feel like manually typing in 300+ IF/ELSE statements.

Is there something sensible I can do where the manager's groups can be compared to the ones in AD? I suspect there must be and I just don't know what it is.

Comment: Oh well, found my answer elsewhere, but here it is for anyone else who might stumble across this.
Using RegEx:

    Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $Boss |
    Where-Object { $_.SamAccountName -match '(?:^GALDN)| ?:^GRP.*MIG$)' } |
    Add-ADGroupMember -Members $SamID

Using -like:

    Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $Boss |
    Where-Object { $_.SamAccountName -like 'GALDN*' -or $_.SamAccountName -like 'GRP*MIG' } |
    Add-ADGroupMember -Members $SamID

Comment: And for some reason my comment isn't editing properly -_-

Comment: Since you've found the solution, it would be better to "Add an answer" instead and answer your own question.  You'll be able to format it correctly in an answer, and other users will know that this question has been resolved after you can accept it.